# Creating virtual class from raw data

Tags: c++, casting

I want to cast a character-array to a virtual class that has the same layout, except for a virtual methos.  How can I do this?

```
        class RecordStruct
    {
    private:
        virtual MStream& write2stream(MStream& os) const = 0;
    public:
        friend MStream& operator<<(MStream& os, const RecordStruct& stru)
        {
            return stru.write2stream( os );
        };

    };

    class VIRT_struct : public  RecordStruct
    {
        char A[7]; char B[8];
        virtual MStream& write2stream(MStream& os) const;

    };

    const RecordStruct* = some_cast<const RecordStruct*>( pdata );
```

Comment: What is the type of `pdata`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast the pointer directly, at least not with defined behavior.  A `RecordStruct` object has a vtable that is used to resolve virtual method calls, and `pdata` is unlikely to contain this data.  As soon as you tried to call a virtual method on the resulting object, you would almost certainly crash.  (If this did work, the cast operator you *would* use is `reinterpret_cast<>`.)

I'd suggest defining a constructor on `VIRT_struct` that takes `pdata` as an argument and extracts data from it into `A` and `B`.

Or, you can have `VIRT_struct` simply contain the same pointer that `pdata` does, and use that pointer to get at the data.  (Remember to clearly define who owns the pointed-at allocation so that it can be correctly deallocated!)

Comment: It is quite a lot of fields.  If I knew the size I could use memcpy.
(But sinze it is virtual I don't know how I can get the exact size of the data)

Comment: @user1987442 If you don't want to copy the data, then store a pointer or reference to the data on the `VIRT_struct` object.